# Flash - TLF Textfield in Gradient

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

They said a mask will work for a text gradient, but using a mask doesn!'t work for me

[image: Masked Text in Player]

What I did is I put a TLF textfield on the top layer, then at a lower layer I added that gray gradient, but masking don't work?! **It ended up with my gray movieclip with hollow text in the middle, my text in the mark is dark orange**. I searched on Google but not many result on this, they all said make a mask like this.

It worked on a classic static field, but not classic dynamic or TLF.

Is there a as3 way or any way to make a gradiented TLF text? Because I saw it displaying at some flash games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try caching as bitmap your text.

```
myText.cacheAsBitmap = true;
background.mask = myText;
```